# toggle audio play back on/off very quickly

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I'm working on a simple project with one view. When the user presses the view, a tone should play, and when they lift their finger up it should stop. Basically like Morse code.

Edit: For clarification, I'm looking for an effect as instant and short as the sound effects the keyboard makes. The UILongPressGestureRecognizer's Min Duration is set to 0.01, so it starts effectively instantly.

The way I have this setup now is like this:

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set up sound files
    var fileLocation = NSString(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Eb", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var error:NSError? = nil

    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: fileLocation), error: &error)
    player.prepareToPlay()
}


@IBAction func pressed(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch gesture.state{

    case .Began:
        player.play()

        //Some other code

    case .Ended:
        player.pause()

        //Some other code

    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Now, this works if the presses are moderately long, but if the press it too short the sound clip never plays. The sound file has no blank space at the beginning, so I know that is not the problem. I'm also sure the gesture recognizer is getting called because the `\\ Some other code` executes just fine.

My question is, is there some other way to make the audio more responsive? I need it to be able to turn on and off very quickly. Are there other playbacks methods in other frameworks, or a way to generate a tone, that would be faster?

Comment: How do you define *too short*, *very quickly*, etc.? 30 seconds? 2 seconds? 0.5 second? And, have you attempted setting breakpoints at the line and check the result?

Comment: If it's "too short" it can't be recognized by a UI*Long*PressGestureRecognizer. It's probably "canceling" if some of the code is still executing.

Comment: To clarify, I want it to turn on and off in something on the order of 0.25 seconds. Think like the default clicking sound the iOS keyboard makes. The UILongPressGestureRecognizer has its Min Duration set to 0.01s, and I'm sure it's working because the animation that is supposed to start and stop along with the sound works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I finally found to this problem is not perfect, but I'll leave it here in case anybody ever stumbles across something similar.

I created a minimum allowable play time, in my case 0.1 seconds. When the button is pressed, and NSTimer begins counting down, and when it reaches 0, if fires a function that sets a flag. When the button is released, it checks if the flag is set, and if it is, stops playback. If the flag is not set, playback continues until the timer reaches zero.